# Cum sum of unique strings - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm aiming to return a cumulative sum of unique strings corresponding to each new row. With below, I'm interested in strings `A-B`. For each subsequent row with the same previous value I want to add 1. But if the value is different, then start the count again. I'm also hoping to pass a parameter where the string is agnostic. As in, the values could be `C-D` or `E-F` instead of `A-B`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['X','A','A','B','B','B','A','B','B','Y'], columns = ['Item'])

L1 = ['X','Y']

df['CumSum'] = np.nan
df.loc[df['Item'].isin(L1), ['CumSum']] = 0

df['CumSum'] = df.groupby(df['Item'].eq('A').cumsum()).cumcount() + 1
```

Intended out:

```
  Item  CumSum
0    X       0
1    A       1
2    A       2
3    B       1
4    B       2
5    B       3
6    A       1
7    B       1
8    B       2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`groupby cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) + [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html#pandas-series-where):

```
L1 = ['A', 'B']  # values to save
df['CumSum'] = (df.groupby(
    df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift()).cumsum()
).cumcount() + 1).where(df['Item'].isin(L1), 0)
```

Or with [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy-where):

```
L1 = ['A', 'B']
df['CumSum'] = np.where(
    df['Item'].isin(L1),
    df.groupby(df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1,
    0
)
```

`df`:

```
  Item  CumSum
0    X       0
1    A       1
2    A       2
3    B       1
4    B       2
5    B       3
6    A       1
7    B       1
8    B       2
9    Y       0
```

---

Creating groups instead from

```
df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift()).cumsum()
```

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    3
4    3
5    3
6    4
7    5
8    5
9    6
Name: Item, dtype: int32
```

By creating groups based on their previous value, sequential values get enumerated.